# Private docker register: request canceled while waiting for connection. From the server register

Tags: docker

I run from one server the docker register and I get this error when I tried to push, but from my pc I can upload correctly. Anyone why this happen? :)

```
Get domain.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

**Docker register command:**

```
sudo docker run -d   --restart=always   --name registry   -v /home/ubuntu/docker/certs:/certs   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key   -p 443:443 registry:2
```

**Docker push image**

```
sudo docker tag test domain.com/test-reg
sudo docker push domain.com/test-reg
```